Can you explain Subterranean Homesick Blues (from Bob Dylan) lyrics?
After learning English at school, one thing a foreigner can do to improve his understanding is to listen songs and focus to what the singer says.
It's not easy all the times. Even with french songs (my native tongue) I'm sometimes unsure of what I'm hearing.
The diction in Subterranean Homesick Blues from Bob Dylan is clear. No trouble with that.
But it is lot of slang, expressions, figures or references to the mood of the times it was written.
Therefore I'm looking for - how could I call this? - a translation in English?  :-) Quite!
Few explanations of what is in its text, when it isn't immediately understandable for who haven't a large knowledge of the English (or U.S.?) slang.
Thanks!
Johnny’s in the basement
Mixing up the medicine
I’m on the pavement
Thinking about the government
The man in the trench coat
Badge out, laid off
Says he’s got a bad cough
Wants to get it paid off
Look out kid
It’s somethin’ you did
God knows when
But you’re doin’ it again
You better duck down the alley way
Lookin’ for a new friend
The man in the coon-skin cap
By the big pen
Wants eleven dollar bills
You only got ten

Maggie comes fleet foot
Face full of black soot
Talkin’ that the heat put
Plants in the bed but
The phone’s tapped anyway
Maggie says that many say
They must bust in early May
Orders from the D.A.
Look out kid
Don’t matter what you did
Walk on your tiptoes
Don’t try “No-Doz”
Better stay away from those
That carry around a fire hose
Keep a clean nose
Watch the plain clothes
You don’t need a weatherman
To know which way the wind blows

Get sick, get well
Hang around a ink well
Ring bell, hard to tell
If anything is goin’ to sell
Try hard, get barred
Get back, write braille
Get jailed, jump bail
Join the army, if you fail
Look out kid
You’re gonna get hit
But users, cheaters
Six-time losers
Hang around the theaters
Girl by the whirlpool
Lookin’ for a new fool
Don’t follow leaders
Watch the parkin’ meters

Ah get born, keep warm
Short pants, romance, learn to dance
Get dressed, get blessed
Try to be a success
Please her, please him, buy gifts
Don’t steal, don’t lift
Twenty years of schoolin’
And they put you on the day shift
Look out kid
They keep it all hid
Better jump down a manhole
Light yourself a candle
Don’t wear sandals
Try to avoid the scandals
Don’t wanna be a bum
You better chew gum
The pump don’t work
’Cause the vandals took the handles                                     


Probably worth pointing out that many lyrics don't have a direct, clear meaning; they're poetry rather than prose, and rhythm, scansion, the sounds of words, and the associations they have for the songwriter are often more relevant than any literal meaning.  And these lyrics in particular are especially obscure!  (As the lack of answers here may indicate.)  So they're probably not the best place to try to improve your understanding of English… just enjoy them as they are.
